# Java - Access variable from another method in main method

Tags: java

This is the full code if anyone can help, I'm basically attempting to make a email availability checker. All I want is too put the variable line into my Jlist so it will output all the emails and be removed from JList if that email has been checked.

```
   class main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        gui.gui();

    }
}
```

|

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

    class tuna {
        public static void tuna() throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("emails.txt"))) {
                String line;


                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    driver.get("https://signup.live.com/signup?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1465840004&rver=6.7.6643.0&wp=&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fwww.msn.com%2fen-us%2fhomepage%2fSecure%2fPassport%3fru%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.msn.com%252f%253focid%253dmailsignout%2526pfr%253d1&id=1184&pcexp=True&bk=1465840005&uiflavor=web&uaid=dc151162984741948b8371ce3e0c865e&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&lic=1");
                    WebElement Email = driver.findElement(By.id("MemberName"));
                    WebElement Refresher = driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName"));
                    WebElement TakenErrorMsg = driver.findElement(By.id("MemberNameError"));
                    Email.sendKeys(line);
                    Refresher.click();
                    Thread.sleep(650);
                    if (TakenErrorMsg.isDisplayed()) {
                        System.out.println(line + " is taken!");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println(line + " is not taken!");
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

|

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class gui extends JFrame {
    public static void gui() {


        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Hotmail availability checker");
        label1.setVisible(true);
        label1.setSize(250, 250);
        label1.setLocation(165, -100);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Emails unchecked");
        label2.setVisible(true);
        label2.setSize(250, 240);
        label2.setLocation(40, -82);




        JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
        b1.setSize(200,50);
        b1.setLocation(140, 300);
        b1.setVisible(true);


        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        final DefaultListModel emailsChecked = new DefaultListModel();
        emailsChecked.addElement("AAA");

        final JList list = new JList(emailsChecked);
        list.setVisible(true);
        list.setVisible(true);
        list.setLocation(20,50);
        list.setSize(150,200);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(list);



        JFrame frames = new JFrame();
        frames.setTitle("Hotmail availability checker");
        frames.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frames.setLayout(null);
        frames.setVisible(true);
        frames.setSize(500, 400);
        frames.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frames.add(b1);
        frames.add(label1);
        frames.add(list);
        frames.add(label2);
        frames.add(scrollPane);


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    tuna.tuna();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `line` is a local variable declared in another method, then you cannot access it from your `main` method.

Local variables in methods are only accessible (in limited circumstances) from classes that are declared within the scope of the local variable; e.g. using an anonymous inner class.  That is clearly not applicable from a `main` method.

I don't know what to suggest as a solution, but there is clearly something rather wrong with the design of your application if one method needs to see the local variables of another method.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback, any idea what I could do differently? too make this work?

Comment: @Macklinguy your question is very generic and that makes it really difficult to provide a good answer. Can you provide more details about what your code is intended to do and what the requirements for your code are? From what I see in your code it looks like you're reading lines from a buffered reader so I would suggest if you need those lines later on that you store them in a variable, have your "other java file" modify or return the variable and have your main method keep a reference to that variable for later use.

Comment: As I said: "I don't know what to suggest as a solution".  For a start, what you seem to be trying to do doesn't make sense ... to me.

Comment: I mean, I want, the variable line which is a string, too go into the JList so it can be seen.

Comment: You will need to start using Java as a OO language, with non-static methods and non-static fields.